# Turtle graphics window won't open

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am trying to use turtle graphics I can't get the pop-up window to open.
I am using Windows 11, python 3.8.10, and VS-code.

I have tried running the turtle screen from a VS file as well as from the Python3 console.

VS code:

```
import turtle
wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.mainloop() # This was added after trying to find an answer online but didn't help.
```

Python console:

```
Python 3.8.10 (default, May 26 2023, 14:05:08)
[GCC 9.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import turtle
>>> s = turtle.Screen()
```

I saw in other issues that the window opens and immediately closes, this is not my issue. In my case, it does not open at all.

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting any errors? If not, try doing a command that modifies the screen or turtle, like:

```
wn.bgcolor("white")
```

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but the window won't open until you tell the turtle or screen to actually do something.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35359395)

Answer (score 0):

To make a turtle screen that remains open you can do this:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.exitonclick()
```

This just makes a blank screen and keeps it on until the user clicks the screen.